# Porting X509Certificate and CryptoConfig from .Net 4.5 to .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, .net-core, x509

I'm porting a .Net 4.5 project to .Net Core, and I get sucked into the function...

```
public bool IsMessageSignatureValid(byte[] bytes, string signature) {
    X509Certificate2 certificate = GetX509Certificate();
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = certificate.PublicKey.Key as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
    return rsa.VerifyData(bytes, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), Convert.FromBase64String(signature));
}
```

- There're no `Key` property in `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey` on .Net Core
- No `CryptoConfig` class in System.Security.Cryptography on .Net Core

Could anyone give me some ideas how to fix it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the enhancements that were made to certificates and RSA in .NET 4.6.  .NET Core 1.0 and 1.1 only allow the new way of doing things, since it works much better on non-Windows systems.

```
public bool IsMessageSignatureValid(byte[] bytes, string signature) {
    // New instance each call? If so, dispose this.
    X509Certificate2 certificate = GetX509Certificate();

    // GetRSAPublicKey returns a new object each time,
    // you should definitely using/Dispose it.
    using (RSA rsa = certificate.GetRSAPublicKey())
    {
        return rsa.VerifyData(
            bytes,
            Convert.FromBase64String(signature),
            HashAlgorithmName.SHA1,
            RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    }
}
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.verifydata

Comment: Yup, I just figured out that minutes ago, anyway thank you!

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you.